# How to print asterisk pattern with asterisk

Tags: c#

I'm doing this for my school library where I need to print asterisk pattern like below with *'s

```
*     *
 *   *
  ***
*******
  ***
 *   *
*     *
```

Below is what I tried,

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Patterns
{
    class Asterisks
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 7;
            
            for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
               for(int j =1; j<=n; j++){
                 if(j==i || j==n-i+1 || i==n/2+1){
                    Console.Write("*");
                 }else{
                    Console.Write(" ");
                 }
              }
               Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs below :

```
*     *
 *   *
  * *
*******
  * *
 *   *
*     *
```

My logic above is faulty, I tried couple of edits on the loops and conditions but somewhere I'm going wrong. Need help to fix this. Thanks

Comment: A good start would be taking the debugger and going through your code step by step and comparing your expectation to what is actually happening.

Comment: A better start would be identifying the *syntax* error(s) in your code.

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: Is it `7 x 7` or `7 x 11`?  The output you are trying to achieve has 11 columns not 7 but the code only produces a `7 x 7` shape

Comment: I understand, I started learning 2 weeks back and referred to other pattern programs from here https://codewithshadman.com/csharp-pattern-programs/. I'm not allowed to copy paste so wrote up. Apologies for the syntax, just expecting some help on the logic part...especially inside 2nd forloop.

Comment: @Martin I manually typed that pattern...7 or 11 anything is fine.

Comment: What martin means, is you have your entire width set to 7, but with the spaces in between your pattern, you get to a total of 11 characters. Therefore, your n should be set to 11 in order to display 7 *s for each line

Comment: You may not handle it in a single loop. The shape looks symmetric aside from the middle line. So you can split it into 3 parts.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Are you sure your edit is what the OP intended?

Comment: @Sweeper, of course. Otherwise I wouldn't have done it. Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the problem as painting a picture line by line and pixel by pixel, starting from the top left (TL) corner and moving to the bottom right (BR).

Depending on the brush/cursor's current position, the program should either "paint" a `*` or a  . This is what the `if` inside the `for` does.

If you only wanted to paint a diagonal going from TL to BR then the `if` only needed one check:

```cs
if (j == i) {
    Console.Write("*");
} else {
    Console.Write(" ");
}
```

Try it out for yourself and you'll see this shape:

```
*      
 *     
  *    
   *   
    *  
     * 
      *
```

Also try and understand how `i` and `j` are changed by the two `for` loops over time and why this works.

For the opposite diagonal we'll have to get the "inverted" value of `i` which is `n - i + 1`. This inverted `i` is what the value of `i` would have been if we were drawing the picture going *right to left*, but still top to bottom (i.e. from TR to BL). Knowing this inverted `i` we can now add an additional check to the `if` that makes the `if` more inclusive and draw on more positions:

```cs
if (j == i              // diag from TL to BR
    || j == n - i + 1   // diag from TR to BL
    ) {
    Console.Write("*");
} else {
    Console.Write(" ");
}
```

This will give us the following shape:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *   
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *
```

Again, try it out for yourself.

The horizontal center line is easier, because it only depends on `i`, but not on `j`. We just have to check if we are currently in the center line:

```cs
if (j == i              // diag from TL to BR
    || j == n - i + 1   // diag from TR to BL
    || i == n / 2 + 1   // center horizontal
    ) {
    Console.Write("*");
} else {
    Console.Write(" ");
}
```

Make sure you understand why the `+ 1` in `n / 2 + 1` is [necessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division).

Similarly we can also include the center vertical line like so:

```cs
if (j == i              // diag from TL to BR
    || j == n - i + 1   // diag from TR to BL
    || i == n / 2 + 1   // center horizontal
    || j == n / 2 + 1   // center vertical
    ) {
    Console.Write("*");
} else {
    Console.Write(" ");
}
```

...and we'll end up with this shape:

```
*  *  *
 * * * 
  ***  
*******
  ***  
 * * * 
*  *  *
```

The only problem now is that we don't want to draw the *whole* vertical line, only it's middle part. So the last check we added to the `if` is *too inclusive*, it needs to be more strict. Only the parts of the vertical line that are right next to the center point should be drawn. Or, more precisely, only the point above and the point below the center point should be drawn. (It doesn't matter if we include or exclude the actual center point in the check, because all other checks will cause it to be drawn anyway).

The cursor is right on the center point when `i == n / 2 + 1` and `j == n / 2 + 1`. The point above the center has an `i` value of `n / 2` and the point below an `i` value of `n / 2 + 2`.

So when `j == n / 2 + 1` is true (we're currently somewhere on the vertical center line) we must also ensure that we're either directly above or below the center point like so:

```cs
if (j == i              // diag from TL to BR
    || j == n - i + 1   // diag from TR to BL
    || i == n / 2 + 1   // center horizontal
    || (j == n / 2 + 1 && (i == n / 2 || i == n / 2 + 2))
    ) {
    Console.Write("*");
} else {
    Console.Write(" ");
}
```

```
*     *
 *   * 
  ***  
*******
  ***  
 *   * 
*     *
```

Comment: Nice way of properly explaining your code!

Answer (score 2):

Break the pattern into parts, and write checks for them individually. If any of checks pass, print a `*`, otherwise a space. This seems to be what you are already doing. You just seem to be missing some disjunctions in your if statement.

Right now, your condition to print a `*` is:

```
j==i || // the "\" part
j==n-i+1 || // the "/" part
i==n/2+1 // the "-" part
```

You really just need one more condition that those two missing positions would match. One way to check for this is to check that the column (`j`) is the middle column, and that the row (`i`) is one away from the middle row.

```
j == n / 2 + 1 && (i == n / 2 + 2 || i == n / 2)
```

There's quite a lot of `+ 1`s in your conditions. You can remove them if you  start your loop at 0. Rather than repeating `n / 2` all the time, you can extract to a variable.

Your code ends up being like this:

```
int n = 7;
int midRow = n / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (j == i ||
            j == n - i - 1 ||
            i == midRow ||
            j == midRow && (i == midRow + 1 || i == midRow - 1))
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  ***  
*******
  ***  
 *   * 
*     *
```

Comment: Just as a nice addition, maybe add the full output of your code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea - you can map your shape using a jagged array, where 1 means a sign in this case'*' and 0 is a space.

So our pattern will be like this:

```
        int[][] myPattern = new int[][]
        {
            new int[] {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 },
            new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            new int[] {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 }
        };
```

If you look at it - represent our asterisk sign.
What you then have to is loop per each item in the jagged array.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < myPattern.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myPattern[j].Length; i++)
            {
                if (myPattern[j][i] > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write('*');
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(' ');
                }

                if (i+1 == myPattern[j].Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

if you want you can remove altogether the patter with all 0's and replace this

```
                if (i+1 == myPattern[j].Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

I have left it in for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Question is, whether OP wishes to "simply" show the output, defined in a multi dimensional array or if they want to actually calculate the results

Comment: @Foitn - that is a good point - if he needs to calculate my implementation will not do. The question doesn't specify it - it wants to print a pattern. I thought that this was the simplest way to define a pattern by mapping.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable way to output some arbitrary pattern. Nothing about those 2 middle lines looks like it should have 3 glyphs, so its entirely arbitrary. Can probably be "calculated" by some convoluted if logic but why would you?!

Comment: Because if this is a school thing, I don't suppose a teacher would really be interested in "just displaying" a specific pattern, I think that it is way more interesting for a student to get to know boolean algebra (if that is the correct term here). On how to properly have these sort of for loops with if statements for printing